# Change Custom Theme's Desktop Label

Tags: 12.04, unity, themes, customization

I'm attempting to write a custom theme for 12.04 and would like to change the upper left-hand corner label for the desktop from "Ubuntu Desktop" to a simple icon.  (See image)

[image: Ubuntu Desktop]
)

In looking through the theme directories, it seems as though this is set somewhere else.  Does anyone know where I might find it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change this in the theme, nor can you set it as an icon.